# Convert string representation of tuple to dict

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have a `string` representation of `tuple` as follows:

```
t = "(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)"
```

I want to convert this to dict like this:

```
d = {'a':'b', 'c':'d', 'e':'f'}
```

I tried doing it in following way

```
>>> l = t.split(',')
>>> l
>>> ['(a', 'b)', '(c', 'd)', '(e', 'f)']

>>> l = [i.replace('(','').replace(')','') for i in l]
>>> l
>>> ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']

>>> dict([(a,b) for a,b in zip(l[::2],l[1::2])])
>>> {'e': 'f', 'c': 'd', 'a': 'b'}
```

This gives me correct result(Order of `dict` elements is not important to me). However this is inefficient as it involves three steps before I can get the required output. Is there a way to get this in two or ideally one operation/statement?

Comment: You should measure the performance before attempting to improve it. That way you'll know if it's necessary and if a speed increase was achieved.

Comment: @GarbageCollector `t` is a string representation of many tuples separated by commas.

Comment: @Chris_Rands In Python they're not necessary.

Comment: About variable names... yes, they need to be defined, as in my comment above.

Comment: @user202729 what variable names need to be defined?

Comment: @GarbageCollector Just try to run it in Python, `NameError: name 'a' is not defined`.

Comment: I am not sure @user202729. I just tried to run it in python shell and it works fine.

Comment: I meant to run `(a,b),(c,d),(e,f)` directly. Anyway... that's not important to the question. Have you tried to measure the performance?

Comment: I just tried with a string with length > 2 million, and the function finishes after less than 0.1 seconds. I'd say that it's fast enough.

Comment: You know that get things in one statement is not necessarily efficient? (code-golf - less code, less things to run. False)

Answer (score 0):

As I already said in the comments:

- Less code doesn't always mean code runs faster.
- If it's not performance-critical, it's not very important to optimize this.
- The performance is already quite fast.

However, the code performs an redundant step: Why using `replace` when you only need to strip away one character from a position you already knew?

Here I write some functions that does the same task.

import random

```python
random.seed(1234)

def f():
    return ''.join(chr(random.randint(65,90)) for _ in range(100))

def g():
    return ','.join('({}, {})'.format(f(), f()) for _ in range(1000))

def ext(t):
    l = t.split(',')
    l = [i.replace('(','').replace(')','') for i in l]
    return dict([(a,b) for a,b in zip(l[::2],l[1::2])])

def ext2(t):
    l = t.split(',')
    return dict([(a[1:],b[:-1]) for a,b in zip(l[::2],l[1::2])])

def ext3(t):
    l = t.split(',')
    return {a[1:] : b[:-1] for a,b in zip(l[::2],l[1::2])}

def ext4(t):
    return dict(x.split(',') for x in t[1:-1].split('),('))

import timeit

t = g()
assert(ext(t) == ext2(t) == ext3(t) == ext4(t))

print(len(t))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: ext (t), number=30))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: ext2(t), number=30))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: ext3(t), number=30))
print(timeit.timeit(lambda: ext4(t), number=30))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZLbaoQwEIavm6fInRNIZdVtoYJPIlJ0zW5TYpQ4C9su@@x2YvbUE8teyBwy/zc/JsMHvvU2mybdDb1D7mrb9h1jIcajUi0kabYUjLVqzdcgcvbgFG6d5VEUv/fawurNwXHeB20Rnp/ky0IIvu4df@Xaeu5GQbKgZiBtvpHkERXB/iD5/iCimKRdjUAbpV/7F@sMUzsE9DzDC47xOBiNQFAROqWOnRpMvVK0gNqRuNRirme49nBTnV21eoVQQi2bcE6Jn/jUA5gyz9NKmjLxUVQXH@l/Rn5ASVnJpswfk@oOenaDvp@5POeBfAN8OHOXgXvtcXfFnzk7T0GSEvh0JiR9ZO/4elB3SiNjSP7oglk9jsohhOvhRXH6Qcc0u6TeAHEG51@PUXYuQxWgcQhg6q5p69xrOA1Jbrddo1yRLW4L0nsF2b2C5S/BNH0B)

As TIO shows, the function `ext3` executes in the least time, a 2x speedup in comparison with OP's original function `ext`.

`ext4` is not faster than `ext3` (although still faster than `ext`), as it avoids the `replace`, but it is one statement. Only useful for code-golf. In reality, how many statements are not important.

Attached result of running the code above, because answers should be self-contained:

```python
204999
0.05400996300159022
0.022308056009933352
0.02011037600459531
0.02612137998221442
```